# Single word or phrase - conspiratorially exchanging glances

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a single word or a phrase for conspiratorially exchanging glances when someone does something inappropriate?

Comment: a "knowing" glance.

Answer (score 1):

They exchanged looks.

It doesn't specifically convey judgment of something inappropriate, just a silent exchange between people. But is a common use of the phrase that two people "exchange looks" to keep a mutual judgment silent.

Answer (score 0):

**"complicit glances"**, not an idiom but may describe what you are looking for.

> complicit (adj) "Involved with others in an activity that is unlawful or morally wrong" [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/complicit)

"Every now and then they would exchange complicit glances."

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Mitch's "a knowing glance",  I think I prefer the lesser-syllabic "a knowing look".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: My answer is "a knowing look".  And I also gave credit to Mitch,  who wrote "a knowing glance", and from whom I am not asking for any clarification.

Comment: However you provide no rationale for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the more contemporary expression "side eye".